# How to run multiple .java files with dependency to YahooFinance jar file in Command Prompt

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-prompt

So I am trying to run my multiple .java files with a dependency to an external jar file. The structure of my program looks like this..

### Folder

- AccountReport.javaDriver.java
- EquityAccount.java
- SavingsAccount.java
- YahooFinanceAPI-3.6.0.jar

The way I must do it is...

"When I grade your homework I will be using the command prompt to compile and run the programs. Ideally, I'd like to be able to compile/run these two commands from the command prompt:

> javac *.java
>
> java Driver

If you are using a jar file, however, it may not be that simple.

Before you hand in your code please copy all of the .java files that you wrote into a new directory. If you are using a jar file put it in the same directory. Then try and build and run the program from the command prompt.

If you have to alter the two commands about please put a comment in your driver that tells me how to build it (to include a classpath, for example).

You may have to rename the class that holds main to "Driver".

If you are using Eclipse, you may also have to remove any package statements that were added for you by Eclipse (you can comment them out if you'd like).

It is up to you to ensure that I can build and run the code!"

I have tried to run the following line "javac -classpath YahooFinance.jar Driver.java" in the command line but I get error messages.

[image: Command Prompt error message]

All of the classpath files compile but once I type "java Driver" the error message pop up

[image: .class files that pop up after I enter "javac -cp YahooFinance.jar *.java]

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: yahoofinance/YahooFinance
        at EquityAccount$StockClass.<init>(EquityAccount.java:167)
        at EquityAccount.addTransaction(EquityAccount.java:42)
        at Driver.main(Driver.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: yahoofinance.YahooFinance
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more

Comment: Please add the error to you question by editing it.

Comment: All of the .class files compile but once I type "java Driver" all of the error messages pop up

Comment: Are your class files in the same directory as your java files?

Comment: Yes they are in the same file, as you can see in the image above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also specify the classpath when you run you code.

```
java -classpath .;YahooFinanceAPI-3.6.0.jar Driver
```

The `.` includes the current directory on the classpath, which is the default, but you're overriding it with the jar, so you now need to explicitly include it.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Jacob>cd Documents

C:\Users\Jacob\Documents>cd Homework_2_Turnin

C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Homework_2_Turnin>javac -classpath YahooFinanceAPI-3.6.0.jar *.java

C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Homework_2_Turnin>java -classpath .:YahooFinance.jar Driver
Error: Could not find or load main class Driver

C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Homework_2_Turnin>java -classpath .:YahooFinanceAPI-3.6.0.jar Driver.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Driver.java

Comment: Why did you add `.java` to the end of the command I suggested?

Comment: C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Homework_2_Turnin>java -classpath .:YahooFinance.jar Driver
Error: Could not find or load main class Driver

Comment: Even when I don't include .java I get an error message

Comment: Sorry. Since you're on windows, you need to use `;` as the separator rather than `:`.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, I am still getting the following error, but at least the program is running!

Comment: C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Homework_2_Turnin>java -classpath .;YahooFinance.jar Driver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: yahoofinance/YahooFinance
at EquityAccount$StockClass.<init>(EquityAccount.java:167)
at EquityAccount.addTransaction(EquityAccount.java:42)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: yahoofinance.YahooFinance
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: According to your screenshot, the name of the jar is not `YahooFinance.jar`.